# C# double.ToString("#.##") method is not printing zero values

Tags: c#

I need to print a double to a string with only 2 decimal places. It works for all values of the double, except for 0, where it creates an empty string.

How can I make it work for all values of a double?

example code:

```
double x = 0.0;
MessageBox.Show(x.ToString("#.##"));
```

Comment: Try `"0.##"` instead of `"#.##"`

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the--custom-specifier) states (for '#'): *"this specifier never displays a zero that is not a significant digit, even if zero is the only digit in the string. It will display zero only if it is a significant digit in the number that is being displayed."* It did exactly what you told it to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do it is this:

```
double x = 0.0;
MessageBox.Show(x.ToString("0.00"));
```

**#** - it's a character that show's not to put the number in(aka ignore it). So when you put **#:##** the app won't show any numbers. When you put "0:00" that tells the program how you want it formated. If you put "0:0000" it's gonna have 4 numbers after the decimal point.